# How to assign a value globally after a service subscription in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to assign a value globally outside of a method in my app component?

My service looks like this:

```
import { NumberInput } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Candidato } from "../interfaces/candidato";
import { Cuestionario } from '../interfaces/cuestionario';
import { Respuesta } from '../interfaces/Respuesta';
import { Verdaderos } from '../interfaces/verdaderos';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CandidateService {

  url="http://localhost:3000/api"

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }



  getPersona(ID:Number):Observable<Candidato[]>{
    return this.http.get<Candidato[]>(this.url + "/persona/searchrh/"+ID)
  }

  deletePersona(ID_RH:Number,ID:Number){
    return this.http.delete<Respuesta>(this.url+"/persona/deleteRH/"+ID_RH+"/"+ID)
  }

  getCandidato(ID:Number):Observable<Candidato>{
    return this.http.get<Candidato>(this.url + "/persona/search/"+ID)
  }

  getCuestionarioRespuestas(ID:Number):Observable<Verdaderos[]>{
    return this.http.get<Verdaderos[]>(this.url + "/cuestionario/"+ID)
  }
}
```

With interface Verdaderos looking like this:

```
export interface Verdaderos{
    Pregunta: number;
}
```

What I get from the service is an object array containing certain IDs belonging to all the "answers" with certain response, the issue here is I need to count them in order to sort them properly.
My method looks like this, with M,N and P being global variables equal to zero.

```
getRespuestasCandidato(ID: Number) {
    this.Persona.getCuestionarioRespuestas(ID).subscribe((data:Verdaderos[]) =>{
      this.conteo = data;
      this.numbers = this.conteo.map(x => x.ID_Pregunta);
      console.log(this.numbers)

      const N2 = this.N1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countN2 = N2.length;
      console.log(countN2)

      const M2 = this.M1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countM2 = M2.length;
      console.log(countM2)

      const P2 = this.P1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countP2 = P2.length;
      console.log(countM2)
      this.N = countN2;
      this.M = countM2;
      this.P = countP2
    })
  }
```

Printing any variable avia console naturally gets me the value I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to assign those values to the global variable in order to plot them using ngx-charts

```
NE = 100 - this.N- this.M- this.P

single = [
    {
      "name": "Narcisismo",
      "value": this.N    },
    {
      "name": "Maquiavelismo",
      "value": this.M
    },
    {
      "name": "Psicopatia",
      "value": this.P
    },
    {
      "name": "No evaluado",
      "value": this.NE
    }
  ];
```

Naturally, single is declared before the constructor, and that's what I need to render a pie chart with the correct data

Is there something wrong with my logic or my syntax? I'm calling the method  this.getRespuestasCandidato(this.ID); "inside" AfterViewInit, but even then, if I change the lifecycle, I haven't been able to get the values I need for my chart

Here's the html:

```
<div class="wrapperuser">
    <div class="container-sm grafico">
        <ngx-charts-pie-chart
        [view]="view"
        [results]="single"
        [gradient]="gradient"
        [legend]="showLegend"
        [labels]="showLabels"
        [doughnut]="isDoughnut">
        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do the variables need to be global? Are you injecting the service and subscribing within the component that’ll consume the NE etc.?

Comment: That's right. I feel my logic is flawed somewhere. The method used to count "the score" and the very basic ng chart are in the same component. That is not secure I all I presume, but it's the only way I've come up with so far.

Comment: Logic looks fine. But unclear on debugging details, will need to see minimal code for trying to use chart and why this isn’t working.

Comment: I'll try setting a stackblitz project, but I'm afraid I'll need my backend and data from the DB. I'm new at angular and node js. Thing is, when debugging via console log, it throws me an "undefined type" when trying to print any variable outside of the service subscription

Comment: It will do. Code is asynchronous by definition. Stackblitz may be overkill, if you post example code of trying to set it in template etc I’ll post answer.

Comment: Edited. Something to note is that "single" is declared before the constructor, and given how my method getRespuestasCandidato() is casted "inside of" ngAfterViewInit, trying to assign them has been an issue

Answer (score 0):

On option is to use pipeable operator `map` to transform the stream into needed data and use the `async` pipe operator in the template. This takes care of subscribing and unsubscribing.

```
single$: Observable<ISingleInterface> = of()

ngOnInit() {
    this.single$ = this.Persona.getCuestionarioRespuestas(ID).pipe(
        map((data: Verdaderos[]) => {
            // calculate `single` as in question
            return single;
        }),
        // the following may be required depending on if ngx-charts needs this
        // startWith(defaultSingleValue)
    );
}
```

```
<div class="wrapperuser">
    <div class="container-sm grafico">
        <ngx-charts-pie-chart
        [view]="view"
        [results]="single$ | async" <---------------- async pipe subscribes and passes value
        [gradient]="gradient"
        [legend]="showLegend"
        [labels]="showLabels"
        [doughnut]="isDoughnut">
        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't include a default via startWith, `single$ | async` will initially pass null and then the data will be pass to the component. You may want to guard fully against this with a wrapping `<div *ngIf="(single$ | async) as single">`

An alternative is to manually subscribe *within the subscribe* assign to variable on the component
`this.single = // calc`
but the same thing will happen. It'll begin with an an initial value that updates once the data is received.